# PostgreSQL Page-level locking

Tags: postgresql, locking

I'm fairly new to postgresql. I've checked out the documentation and I can't find anything about how to do page-level locking.

I understand that I can set a table into a locking mode like this:
LOCK TABLE  myTable IN LOCKMODE ROW EXCLUSIVE;

How would I implement page level locking for my session? Let me know if it seems that I have a misunderstanding of the fundamentals.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have page level locking.

Comment: Actually, Postgres *does* have page-level locking, related to shared buffer pool. But this is an internal matter that should be transparent to application developers. See section 13.3.3 of current doc page, [Explicit Locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you *want* to do explicit page level locking? You don't control what is on each page, so you'd be locking some arbitrary collection of data. What purpose would that serve?

I think you're looking for [row-level locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html), which is accomplished using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` or `SELECT ... FOR SHARE`.

PostgreSQL upgrades row-level locks to page-level locks internally in a few places like serializable snapshot predicate tracking, buffer management, etc. It'll do this when there are too many row level locks and they're becoming a performance issue. You don't need to care about this, as this will have almost no effect on you at the SQL level. Normal row locks - as acquired by `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, `SELECT ... FOR SHARE` etc - are AFAIK never upgraded to page-level locks, as doing so would increase the probability of deadlocks.

If you're really convinced you want page-level locking, please explain what problem you're trying to solve in more detail and why row-level or table-level locking don't do the job.

See:

- [Explicit locking - PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html)
- [`SELECT ... FOR [UPDATE|SHARE]`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) - row level locking
- [`LOCK`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-lock.html) - table level locking
- [Locking in PostgreSQL](http://rhaas.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/locking-in-postgresql.html) is a more advanced discussion of locking